# Does a free JavaScript / ActionScript interpreter for Batch Processing exists?

Tags: javascript, file-io, converters, interpreter, batch-processing

I'm looking for a way to write JavaScript or ActionScript and have it read to make some batch processing tasks (converting sound files to another format, plus writing out an XML file list of the files processed).

The only Macro / Batch Processing language I've used at this point is AutoIt v3 (for Windows), but it uses something like VBScript which I find difficult to get used to.

Is there any interpreter / engine out there that can execute JavaScript "commands", with some extensions to do files and directory writing, reading, and executing other console commands / executables?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/).

It allows you to execute headless JavaScript outside the context of any web browser.

From a Node JS program, you have access to a bunch of APIs to handle files, network, etc...

Comment: And has less baggage than, say, Flash would.  :)

Comment: Oh yeah absolutely! I was considering JSFL as a last resort, having to open up Flash Pro CS6 just to do some batch processing would be ridiculous (even though my tasks are probably revolving around it anyways). :)